# Navigate through SAS Project's OutputDatasets using C#

Tags: c#, sas

I've been trying to navigate through a SAS Project's output datasets using the `SAS.EG.Scripting library` for C#, but I keep getting an empty collection of datasets, even though the dataset is correctly generated on SAS Server.

I tried to follow the steps explained on this article, which is the only resource about SAS automation I've found researching the web: [Not Just for Scheduling: Doing More with SAS® Enterprise Guide® Automation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/examples/SASGF2012/Hemedinger_298-2012.pdf).

The code I've wrote so far is below:

```
public static void RunSASProject()
{
    SAS.EG.Scripting.Application EGApp = new SAS.EG.Scripting.Application();
    EGApp.SetActiveProfile("almarci");

    SAS.EG.Scripting.Project EGProject = (SAS.EG.Scripting.Project)EGApp.New();
    SAS.EG.Scripting.Code oCode = (SAS.EG.Scripting.Code)EGProject.CodeCollection.Add();

    try
    {
        oCode.Server = "SASCORP";
        oCode.UseApplicationOptions = false;
        oCode.GenSasReport = false;
        oCode.Name = "Testing";
        oCode.Text = "LIBNAME SRC '/home/cau004/aj/dccvoj/sotcpc/giad/workgroup/Apoio'; DATA SRC.CARS; SET SASHELP.CARS; OUTPUT; RUN;";

        oCode.Run();
        oCode.Log.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\almarci\Desktop\SAS\LogSAS" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyy HHmmss") + ".log");
        oCode.TaskCode.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\almarci\Desktop\SAS\TaskSAS" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyy HHmmss") + ".txt");

        SAS.EG.Scripting.OutputDatasets outputDatasets = (SAS.EG.Scripting.OutputDatasets)oCode.OutputDatasets;
        foreach (SAS.EG.Scripting.OutputData outputData in outputDatasets)
        {
            Console.Write(outputData.Name.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        EGApp.Quit();
    }
}
```

The basic steps it performs are the following:
1) Instantiate an Application object;
2) Define the profile that will be used for connecting to the server;
3) Create a new project;
4) Add a Code object to the recently created project;
5) Set up the Code object properties (Name, Text - which is the SAS command that will be executed);
6) Run the Code object;
7) Save the Code log and command text on .txt files;
8) Iterate through Code's OutputDatasets collection. This is where I get the strange behavior, since even though the code run successfully, the collection items's count is set to zero.

Anyone has already faced this kind of problem? Have I forgot to write some key word on SAS command or to set some property of the objects involved?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I know zero about C#/SAS integration, but Alan Churchill (savian.net) posts regularly on SAS-L (sas-l@listserv.uga.edu) about C#/SAS integration, so if you don't get a satisfactory response you might try crossposting the question there.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'll have a look at this website.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote the paper that you referenced.

There were some automation-related fixes in SAS Enterprise Guide in 4.3, post-release.  You didn't say which version you have here, but this issue is best tracked with SAS Technical Support who can advise on hotfixes.

Also, for a higher concentration of SAS expertise, consider posting such questions to the [SAS Enterprise Guide discussion forum](https://communities.sas.com/community/support-communities/sas_enterprise_guide).